# Convert HTML in a database to XHTML using ASP.NET

Tags: vb.net, validation

I have a large amount of non-compliant HTML stored in database tables that I need to make validate.

I thought of pulling it into an inline editor like X-Standard that would do a conversion, but is there an easier way to do this via VB.NET?

Comment: I would like to do something similar with the HTML generated by Blogger.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).

From [tidy's documentation](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html):

> Tidy reads HTML, XHTML and XML files
>   and writes cleaned up markup. For HTML
>   variants, it detects and corrects many
>   common coding errors and strives to
>   produce visually equivalent markup
>   that is both W3C compliant and works
>   on most browsers. **A common use of Tidy
>   is to convert plain HTML to XHTML.**

Answer (score 0):

HTML Tidy is probably the best option.

If it's for a one-off conversion it might be easier to use a PHP script (where TIDY is built-in) to do the work; otherwise you'll have to wrap a COM object instead to use it with VB.NET (more info [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ZetaHtmlTidy.aspx) if you want to do that.

Comment: The environment only supports ASP.NET.

Answer (score -1):

By embedding a WYSIWYG editor on a detail page (tinyMCE), I was able to load the bad HTML and let the editor do the work of creating very close to valid code.